# Excluding Qt structures from Project documentation in doxygen

Tags: qt, doxygen

I'm documenting a project built in Qt using doxygen, my problem is that classes and structures from Qt such as QString is being documented.

I want to exclude all QString types from my documentation and only keep the ones i declare and implement.

I know that this should be done some way in the doxyfile, but i have no idea how to do it. Any idea??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you keep Qt headers in your project directory?

Comment: That's indeed weird, unless you have a copy of Qt in your sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the doxygen exclude property:

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html